# Node.js web-scraping

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to scrape some code, to get a link, and some text from a paragraph. But for some reason my code dosen't work, i have tried alot, and every time, it just gives me undifined.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://bitskins.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('p', '.chat-box-content').each(function(i, element){
        if($(this).attr('style') == 'height: 15px;'){
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });
  }
});
```

https://gyazo.com/b80465474a389657c44aeeb64888a006

I only wan it to return the second and the third line, so the link and the price, but do i have to do? I'm new and i lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you request the page, the chat box is a collapsed/hidden state, and all the <p> links (which are apparently placeholders) are empty. If open the chat box, some JavaScript on the page runs and populates the list.

Fortunately you don't need the scrape the screen at all. The page invokes an API to populate the list. You can just call the API yourself.

```
var request = require('request');

request.post('https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_last_chat_messages', function (error, response, data) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
      dataObject.data.messages.forEach(function (message) {
          // For some reason the message is JSON encoded as a string...
          var messageObject = JSON.parse(message);
          // The message object has "message" field.
          // Just use a regex to parse out the link and the price.
          var link = messageObject.message.match(/href='([^']+)/)[1];
          var price = messageObject.message.match(/\$(\d+\.\d+)/)[1];
          console.log(link + " " + price);
      });
  }
});
```

You probably will want to add better error-handling, convert the price into a number, etc.

Comment: OMFG you are an herro, but i dont understand all the /\$(\d+\.\d+)/, how do i make it display the % off ?

Comment: Mark my answer correct and I'll tell you about the slashy stuff. :-)

Comment: Thanks. You know it's all about the points. An expression of the form /whatever/ is a regular expression, which describes a text pattern. You can pass it to the match function of a string to search the string for the pattern.

Comment: The regular expression \$(\d+\.\d+) means: find a '$' (there's a backslash in front to escape it, because normally '$' in a regular expression means "end of string," but we want a literal '$'), followed by at least one digit (\d+), followed by a period (again escaped with backslash because normally '.' means "any character"), followed by at least one digit. The digit-matching part is wrapped in parentheses which makes it into  "capture group."

Comment: Assuming the regular expression matches the string, you'll get back an array-like object. Element 0 of the array is the entire matched portion of the string. Elements 1 through N are the capture groups that you defined. So in both cases I use capture group, so I get just the digits from the price, and just the href attribute from the link.

Comment: so, of what you are saying is that this will give the % off /(\d+\.\d+)\%/ but when i run it its giving error, sorry im so bad at this.. What would i do to get the % off, could u send me that bit so i can compare and see what you have done. that would help alot

Comment: To get the percent off, just search for another regular expression, something like /(\d+)% off/ and then again take the first capture group.

Comment: The percent off is just a single integer so /\d+\.\d+/ will fail because there's no period there.

Comment: If you guys need to create a web scraper and save it on cloud then you could use: https://webscrapers.co/ . They offer free plan and they use nodejs.

You can even run different scrapers at the same time, all asynchronously.